# How to Download and open file in iOS in flutter?

Tags: ios, iphone, flutter

I want to download a file and then open it.
It is working fine on:
Android
iOS Simulator
But on iPhone I get the exception

> Filesystem exception : Cannot create file, path = 'var/mobile/Container/Data/Application/{ID}/Documents2743.pdf' (OS Error: Operation not permitted, errno = 1)

I have written the code below.

```
PermissionStatus _permissionStatus = await PermissionHandler()
    .checkPermissionStatus(PermissionGroup.storage);
if (_permissionStatus == PermissionStatus.granted) {
  FileUtils.mkdir(['/sdcard/h8subscriber/']);
  FileUtils.mkdir(['/sdcard/h8subscriber/documents/']);
  if (Platform.isAndroid) {
    dirloc = "/sdcard/h8subscriber/documents/";
  } else {
    dirloc = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
  }

  Dio dio = Dio();
  var randid = random.nextInt(10000);
  try {
    FileUtils.mkdir([dirloc]);
    await dio.download(fileURL, dirloc + randid.toString() + ".pdf",
        onReceiveProgress: (receivedBytes, totalBytes) {
      setState(() {
        downloading = true;
        progress =
            ((receivedBytes / totalBytes) * 100).toStringAsFixed(0) + "%";
      });
      print("downloading");
    });
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }

  setState(() {
    downloading = false;
    progress = "";
    path = dirloc + randid.toString() + ".pdf";
    _isLoading = false;
    showAlertOk(
        'Download Successfull',
        'Your downloaded file is here..\n'
            '$path',
        path);
  });
} else if (_permissionStatus == PermissionStatus.restricted) {
  bool isOpened = await PermissionHandler().openAppSettings();
  showToast(context, 'Permission Denied!');
} else if (_permissionStatus == PermissionStatus.unknown) {
  dirloc = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;

  Dio dio = Dio();
  var randid = random.nextInt(10000);
  try {
    FileUtils.mkdir([dirloc]);
    await dio.download(fileURL, dirloc + randid.toString() + ".pdf",
        onReceiveProgress: (receivedBytes, totalBytes) {
      setState(() {
        downloading = true;
        progress =
            ((receivedBytes / totalBytes) * 100).toStringAsFixed(0) + "%";
      });
    });
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }

  setState(() {
    downloading = false;
    progress = "";
    path = dirloc + randid.toString() + ".pdf";
    _isLoading = false;
    showAlertOk(
        'Download Successfull',
        'Your downloaded file is here..\n'
            '$path',
        path);
  });
} else {
  showToast(context, 'Permission Denied!');
  setState(() {});
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I don't know if this was the desired outcome, but the I am able to download file by using getTempDirectory() instead of getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()